# Select FIRST X from query, but get count (for example for paging)

Tags: sql, firebird

I want to return the first x rows, but also need the total number of items in my select. In MSSQL I figured it out, but I didn't find a solution to the the same in Interbase.

Does such statement exist also for Firebird?

And one general question, is such embedded function (also in MSSQL) actually faster than to execute a second statement in order to get the total rowcount?

Comment: how do you do in MSSQL?

Comment: Are you using Firebird or InterBase? They are not the same since Firebird was forked 19 years ago. If Firebird, what version of Firebird (eg in Firebird 3 it is a lot easier than in earlier versions)? Also as Dani asked, show how you solved it in Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: In SQL its pretty easy. Just by adding this part to the SELECT (when selecting the rows) "numberofrows= COUNT(myrow) OVER()".Actually it would be perfect if such statement exists for interbase and firebird (since I have both databases in use), but for the beginning just firebird would also be fine

Comment: You should edit your question with that information, in any case Firebird 3 supports `COUNT(myrow) OVER()`

Comment: In any case, I have removed the InterBase tag, because having to take into account two different database systems will make this too broad to answer (even if they share the same origin). If you also need to know for recent InterBase versions, you should ask a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Firebird 3, you can use [window functions](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs):

```
select count(*) over(), column1, column2, etc
from sometable
where somecondition
order by something
fetch first 10 rows only
```

This uses the [`fetch` clause](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-dml-offsetfetch) introduced in Firebird 3.

In earlier versions doing this is a bit harder, but for example in Firebird 2.1 and higher, you could use a common table expression to prevent having to repeat the query and conditions:

```
with actualquery as (
  select column1, column2, etc
  from sometable
  where somecondition
)
select (select count(*) from actualquery), column1, column2, etc
from actualquery
order by something
rows 10
```

This uses the [`rows` clause](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-rows) (which is similar to `select first 10`)

Comment: Nice solution, although it does not make much sense to fetch count value multiple times at each row. Later you need to "separate" it or take it into account during data/fields iteration/management. But if you want to get count and data in one shot, this is the way.

Comment: Thank you for the  answer, thats what I was looking for. But to the other part of the question, do you know if its faster to execute the rowcount with the select statement, or to run one additional query in order to get the results (or is it dependent on the complexity of the query itself)

Comment: @Marcodor the question is if the rowcount select is internally somehow optimized and not fetched for every row

Comment: Needs to be tested, but even it is estimated once, its not so convenient for later field management, for example direct output to JSON format for a REST service. As I said, if performance is the definitive factor and ordering/where is complex, then another aproach is needed.

Comment: @Marcodor Given the subquery is not correlated with the individual row, the count should not be calculated for each row AFAIK, but just once per query execution (although I'm not 100% sure if Firebird optimizes that or not).

Comment: @rimes It is hard to say for certain, doing it this way prevents the overhead of executing multiple queries, but may hinder efficiency in query execution itself. I'd suggest to not bother with determining the total count, and just support infinite paging until there really are no more rows (and consider using keyset pagination instead of using offsets). Having to count all rows can be very inefficient for very large tables, which would make your query a lot slower compared to not querying for the count (whether using a separate query or not). You could consider just querying the count once.

Comment: Just did a test, unfortunately FB3 optimizer is not so smart enough (yet), and evaluate count for each row.

Comment: Ok, thank you both, I will mark the question as solved

Comment: @rimes, just think twice using `window` functions, not applicable in this context. A query like `select count(*) over(), T.ID, T.NAME from TA_TEST T offset 100000 rows fetch first 20 rows only` on a table with 650k records is executed in 5.4s. Two requests runs in 60ms (data) and count(320ms) resulting in near 0.4s.

Comment: @Marcodor - thank you for the response. I think at the end, with all the information I got, I will go with 2 queries. But now I also know that its possible to do it with just one query in Firebird too

Comment: @Marcodor Interesting datapoint, I had expected Firebird to be a bit more efficient in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

You need two separate requests.

One is to receive limited rows set using SQL compliant `offset` & `fetch` starting with Firebird 3 or alternatively `rows` clause or `first` & `skip`:

```
select field1, field2
from mytable
[where conditions]
[offset 0 rows] fetch first 10 rows only
```

Another one is to receive total record count:

`select count(*) from mytable [where conditions]`

Note, last query may be costly on complex queries and/or big amount data. Usually on large amount of data another approaches are used. One is dedicated FTS engines, like SphinxSearch.
Google for example give you an approximate results count.

Comment: Contrary to what some parts of the Firebird documentation claim, `rows` is not a SQL compliant clause. The SQL standard clauses are the `offset`/`fetch` clauses introduced in Firebird 3.

Comment: Strange, even FB core devs argues that `rows` come from the standard when they implemented it along with already existed `first`. But, indeed, from FB3, `fetch` will be more dbms agnostic to use.

Comment: I'm not sure why they thought it was defined in the SQL standard, maybe it was based on an early draft of a SQL standard. In any case `rows` itself has never been in a finalized published SQL standard.